# Integral of polynomial times exponential

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve this indefinite integral:

$$\int x^{-1/4} e^{-2/3 x^{3/2}} \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Have you tried any techniques? It is accepted to at least mention what you've tried.

Comment: what makes you think this has an elementary solution?

Comment: Integration by parts doesnt work in principle, I wonder if there is any choice of u and dv that renders it solvable

Comment: Substitute $y = x^{3/4}$. The integral becomes $\int\dfrac{4}{3}e^{-2/3 y^2}\mathrm{d}y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to make it $\Gamma$ so substituting $t=\frac 23x^{\frac 32}$ to have $e^{-t}$.

$dt=x^{\frac 12}dx$

$\displaystyle \int x^{-\frac 14}e^{-t}x^{-\frac 12}dt=\int x^{-\frac 34}e^{-t}dt=\sqrt{\frac 23}\int t^{-\frac 12}e^{-t}dt=\sqrt{\frac 23}\ \gamma(\frac 12,t)=\sqrt{\frac {2\pi}3}\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t})$